# function to print all elements inside a list into a rectangle

Tags: python, python-3.x

Lets say I have a list:

`li = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`

I need to make a rectangle with dimension 5*4 with all elements inside the list. Which should output (output is plain string, not list):

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
```

How to do this? Beside that, I need to find the general formula that would allow me to create a rectangle of `length*width` dimension that can take input from list of any length.

Comment: The length of the list needs to match the dimensions given, e.g. 3x2 needs six elements not more not fewer. What have you tried to far? It sounds more like your posting your assignment than asking a specific question here.

Comment: You want to print the numbers to the console based on the length/width criteria, or you want to  create a list of lists, or what? Can you be more specific, and yeah, please share with us what you have tried so far.

Comment: deleted my code since it does not work. output should be plain string, not a list, elements separated by space. I tried nested loops, also tried slicing the list but did not succeed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working code:

```
li = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

width = 5

length = len(li)//width 

for i in range(length):
    print(li[i*width:width*(i+1)])
```

Comment: could you explain a bit what happened on the last line of print? what should i modify so the final result would be a plain text instead of lists?

Comment: @theodorusalvin, For example, you have a list of 20 elements and you want a width of 5:
the length will be 4 so we are iterating in the range(4) which is 0,1,2,3.
indexing the list li[i*width:width(1+i)] we are printing slices of the list.

1. iteration i = 0   => li[0*width:width*(1+0)] e.g. li[0:5]
2. iteration I =1   => li[1*width:width(1+1)] e.g. li[5:10]  and so on.

The second part of your question is hard to answer since the definition of a "plain text" is dependent on your output system. Do you want to Print it on a paper? or display it in a GUI?

Comment: i just want to print it out on a notepad .txt file. nothing fancy.

Comment: then you have to open a file with write permissions and iterate through the lists while putting each value into the file with a separator and a line terminator at the and of each line.

Answer (score 0):

I did like this:

```
def list_rect(li,dim1,dim2):
    i=0
    for line in range(dim2):
        for col in range(dim1):
            if i<len(li):
                print(li[i],end=' ')
                i+=1
            else:
                i=0
                print(li[i],end=' ')
        print()
```